# Check the buffer on nested loops

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on java project based on analysis network traffic. I created classes which are uploading data from input and output files in pcap extension  (I uploaded from them time and packet's size). I have a problem with main logarithm which task is checking a buffer condition. I have to check how many times and how long buffer was empty, how many times was unsuccessful attempt to output packet from the buffer and final buffer size.

I created logic in analysis_buffer method, which sets the time chronological, it's mean: if the output_time is bigger than input_time, output_size is adding to buffer(buffer_size), if input_size is bigger, input_size is subtracting from buffer.

I'm using nested loops, first on input file length, second loop(inside) on output file length. Application is working, but finally output is not correctly, the variables are equal 0(only buffer size is much too big) . I have no idea what else I have to change in code, any suggestions?

```
import org.jnetpcap.util.PcapPacketArrayList;

public class Buffer {

int buffer_size =0;      //initial size the buffer
int failed_attempt =0;    //count unsuccessful attempt to output packet from the buffer
double time_empty = 0;    //time for which buffer was empty
int count_empty =0;       //count for which buffer was empty

public Buffer(int buffer_size) {
    this.buffer_size = buffer_size;
}

public Buffer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public void analysis_buffer(PcapPacketArrayList packetArrayList, PcapPacketArrayList packetArrayList2, double[] input_time, double[] output_time, int[] input_size, int[] output_size) {


    for (int i = 0; i < packetArrayList.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < packetArrayList2.size(); j++) {

            // if output time is greater than input time, add input size to main buffer size
            if (input_time[i] < output_time[j]) {
                buffer_size = buffer_size + input_size[i];              
                }

            //  if input time is greater than output time, we have 3 options
            //  1. buffer size is greater than output size packet and output is subtracting from buffer size
            //  2. buffer size is smaller than output packet - buffer size is automatically equal 0 
            //  3. buffer size is equal 0, I'm increasing unsuccessful attempt to get out of the buffer and saves time when buffer was empty 

            else if (input_time[i] > output_time[j]) {

                    if(output_size[j] < buffer_size) {                                      
                        buffer_size = buffer_size - output_size[j];
                        }

                    if(output_size[j] > buffer_size) {
                        buffer_size = 0;
                        count_empty++;
                        }

                    if(buffer_size == 0) {
                        failed_attempt++;
                        time_empty = time_empty + (output_time[j+1]-output_time[j]);
                        }
                    }               

            // if input time is equal output time, add and subtract packets from buffer size, or buffer size is automatically equal 0
            else if (input_time[i] == output_time[j]) {

                if(output_size[j] < buffer_size) {
                    buffer_size = buffer_size + input_size[i] - output_size[j];
                    }

                if(output_size[j] > (buffer_size + input_size[i])){
                    buffer_size = 0;
                    count_empty++;
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }


public void check_buffer() {

    System.out.println("Initial buffer size was 0");
    System.out.println("Final buffer size: " + buffer_size +".");
    System.out.println("Buffer was empty " + count_empty +" times.");
    System.out.println("Failed attempt to output data from the buffer: " + failed_attempt +" times.");
    System.out.println("Total time for which the buffer was empty: " + time_empty + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

My output:

Initial buffer size was 0

Final buffer size: 1227700210.

Buffer was empty 1 times.

Failed attempt to output data from the buffer: 0 times.

Total time for which the buffer was empty: 0.0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with these values:

```
String[] p = new String[4];
String[] p2 = new String[4];
double[] it = {5432d, 4234d, 6345d, 64320d, 8534d};
double[] ot = {5436d, 4234d, 6342d, 64326d, 8534d};
int[] is = {45, 654, 79, 16354, 4563};
int[] os = {65, 641, 98, 23346, 9846};
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.analysis_buffer(p, p2, it, ot, is, os);
buffer.check_buffer();
```

And I got this result:

```
Initial buffer size was 0
Final buffer size: 16354.
Buffer was empty 3 times.
Failed attempt to output data from the buffer: 3 times.
Total time for which the buffer was empty: 62200.0 seconds.
```

The `failed_attempt` and `time_empty` variables are modified only in this place:

```
if(buffer_size == 0) {
  failed_attempt++;
  time_empty = time_empty + (output_time[j+1]-output_time[j]);
}
```

I think that the condition hasn't been met (with your test values), and maybe neither the next:

```
if(output_size[j] > buffer_size) {
  buffer_size = 0;
  count_empty++;
}
```

and

```
else if (input_time[i] > output_time[j]) {
```

*BTW, try to fix this:*

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Buffer.analysis_buffer(Buffer.java:47)
```

With these values:

```
String[] p = new String[5];
String[] p2 = new String[5];
double[] it = {5432d, 4234d, 6345d, 64320d, 8534d};
double[] ot = {5436d, 4234d, 6342d, 64326d, 8534d};
int[] is = {45, 654, 79, 16354, 4563};
int[] os = {65, 641, 98, 23346, 9846};
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.analysis_buffer(p, p2, it, ot, is, os);
buffer.check_buffer();
```

Comment: I check application with your example values but still nothing, error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5. I can change the initial j variable on loop on j=1, condition from `time_empty = time_empty + (output_time[j+1]-output_time[j]);` to `... +(output[j]-output[j-1]`. If remove the whole line, nothing happens when I do run.

Comment: I made at the same exchanges in my code and final output is still wrong, buffer size is too much, other variables are equal 0